# ¿Cómo ocultar el valor de un xrtablecell en base a otro valor en devexpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Buen día.
Estoy en la elaboración de reportes en VS2013 con Devexpress. Tengo el raro problema de querer mostrar los valores de un binding en las columnas [**1 a 30**], [**31 a 60**], [**etc**], cuando el valor de [**Dias**] es correspondiente a los valores de los encabezados de las columnas... El detalle es que sólo debo mostrar el valor decimal en la columna correspondiente y en su defecto, ocultar los otros. Quise utilizar la propiedad *Visible*, pero no me funciona adecuadamente, pues me muestra todos los valores en la primer columna y no es la manera en la que quiero mostrar.
Ojalá puedan ayudarme.  Gracias. 
 Les adjunto una imagen para ejemplificar mi duda. 
[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Mas alla de que no tengo idea de como solucionar tu problema, en el segundo grafico querias que el numero fuera el de la tercera columna no? porque tiene 69 dias de vencidos (y si es asi, quiere decir que explicaste bien la pregunta)

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación @gbianchi...
En cuánto a mi problema, así es, tienes razón. Iría en la 3er columna. Lo voy a corregir para poder encontrar la solución. Gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar el evento [BeforePrint](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.BeforePrint.event) asociado a cada celda y determinar si imprimir el control a través de la propiedad `Cancel` del `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs` que se le pasa al evento o modificar el contenido de la celda, por ejemplo, supongamos que `XRTableCell1A30` contendrá los datos correspondientes a días de 1-30, sería algo así:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
// ...

private void XRTableCell1A30_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    int dias = GetCurrentColumnValue<int>("dias");
    decimal valor = GetCurrentColumnValue<decimal>("valor");
    bool debo_imprimir = false;//determinar si se debe imprimir o no de acuerdo a los días y el valor

    if(!debo_imprimir) {
        e.Cancel = true; //o hacer ((XRControl)sender).Text = string.empty;
    }
    //otras condiciones
}
```